# Open Data platform from scratch

Tags: api, uses-of-open-data, ckan, data-portal, rest

I am doing research on how to build an open data platform with a web portal and a REST interface without relying on a turnkey solution.

I found different solutions: CKAN, Socrata, OpenDataSoft and Junar.

But they all lack documentation regarding the different technologies they use in order to have such system working, and why they used them. Also, Twitter documentation is very detailed, but obviously I can't find anything about their Rest API architecture.

Only CKAN has good documentation, but their architecture description doesn't go much into details of the different software stacks it uses, because I guess I need more than a front end, a load balancer, a backend and a database to make it work.

Comment: super unpopular opinion in this space: but simply publishing data in HTML properly goes a very long way.

Comment: Somehow, I don't get your question, as I literally can't find it (no question mark). What are you looking for? Advice on REST architecture? Use another stackexchange Plattform. How to publish? Look here: https://www.w3.org/TR/dwbp/

Comment: Use hypermedia and established protocols, don't go down the route of defining URL structures...

Comment: why would you not define URL structures?

Comment: Defining URL structure is not flexible to changes in your application. It is not a requirement of REST architecture to define ANY URL structure.

Comment: agreed to all that, but disagree on defining uri/url/urns. do so, but do so with caution/foresight, planning always for future facing endpoints https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI